# Concatenation error: Cannot concatenate media using NReco Video Converter for .NET (C#)

Tags: c#, video, error-handling, ffmpeg

I want to concatenate two videos into one using Video Converter for .NET (C#) FFMpeg wrapper
but I have got "cannot concatenate media" exception.. am i missing something or not..
Here is my Source Code:

```
 var ffMpeg = new NReco.VideoConverter.FFMpegConverter();
    NReco.VideoConverter.ConcatSettings set = new NReco.VideoConverter.ConcatSettings();

    string videoRootPath = @"E:\Sam\Recording Feature\WebApplication2\WebApplication2\Video\";
    string tobename = "test";

    string[] _fileNames = { @"E:\Sam\Recording Feature\WebApplication2\WebApplication2\Video\1.mov",
                                        @"E:\Sam\Recording Feature\WebApplication2\WebApplication2\Video\2.mov"};

    ffMpeg.ConcatMedia(_fileNames, videoRootPath + tobename + ".mov", NReco.VideoConverter.Format.mov, set);
```

Please Help

Answer (score 0):

The most common reason why files cannot be merged into one resulting file is different frame size and/or frame rate (all input files should have the same frame size and rate).

Also note that ContactMedia just invokes FFMpeg with the following parameters:

```
ffmpeg.exe -i [file1] -i [file2] -i [file3] -filter_complex "concat=n=3:v=1:a=1 [v] [a]"  -map "[v]"  -map "[a]"  [outputFile]
```

You may run it from command line for your files and see what is wrong. Note that if you want to use another approach for merging video files (FFMpeg supports several ways how to do that) you may use Invoke or ConvertMedia methods of FFMpegConverter class.

Comment: Thank you for reply... it is very informative for me :)
so basically the error is because of frame size but for my confirmation i also want to ask is there any problem in merging .mov files? because i have got in my mind that may be its because it cannot merge .mov files
and if possible please provide me some useful links to use FFMpeg converter in my asp.net application
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you used Splicer?
below is the link for reference.
https://splicer.codeplex.com/discussions/66271

Comment: Yup i already tried Splicer but what i have found that it only supports avi and wmv files... so its not useful for me :)

Answer (score 0):

```
 string video1 = @"D:\Video\vid1.mp4";
            string video2 = @"D:\Video\vid2.mp4";
            string newvid = @"D:\Video\finalvid.mp4";
            var ffMpeg = new FFMpegConverter();
            ConcatSettings set = new ConcatSettings();
            ffMpeg.ConcatMedia(new string[] { video1,video2 }, newvid, Format.mp4, set);
```